# Hilbert function and chern class

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

It suddenly comes to me. I realize that there are some formal equivalance between Hilbert polynomial and Chern classes.
Hilbert polynomial comes from the rational function on the graded module. And it is additive. Chern classes reveal some  polynomial relation in cohomology group (which is graded) and it can be reduced to a simple rational function. And it is also additive on a exact sequence.

There must be some geometric correspondance berween these two, more then just module-theoretic relation. But to me, it is not clear yet. Can someone explain to me this?

Comment: The Hilbert polynomial is for sheaves on projective space, where you should apply the Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch formula:


http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch_formula

Comment: I think the question is a bit unclear. What kind of 'geometric correspondence' are you referring to? As Allen points out the Riemann-Roch theorem gives an explicit formula for the Hilbert polynomial $P(n)=\chi(\mathcal{O}(n))$ in terms of certain Chern classes. 